# Nltk Wordnet not lemmatizing word even with POS tag

Tags: nltk, wordnet, lemmatization

When I do `wnl.lemmatize('promotional','a')` or `wnl.lemmatize('promotional',wordnet.ADJ)`, I get merely `'promotional'` when it should return `promotion`. I supplied the correct POS, so why isn't it working? What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Lemmatization only changes between inflected forms, so the noun "promotion" isn't a lemma of the adjective "promotional".

Note that your noun *is* included as a pertainym for the lemma.

```
 wn.synsets('promotional')[0].lemmas()[0]             
 Lemma('promotional.a.01.promotional')
 wn.synsets('promotional')[0].lemmas()[0].pertainyms()     
 [Lemma('promotion.n.01.promotion')]
```